# Mimic UILabel's orientation-change behavior using drawRect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawrect

For performance reasons (inside my subclassed `UITableViewCell`), I'm experimenting with drawing text directly with `drawRect`, rather than adding `UILabel` subviews.

And in order for the text to be redrawn upon orientation change, I've set the view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [@"foo" drawInRect:CGRectInset(rect, 10, 10)
              withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
}
```

Scrolling is much faster now, and it all works perfectly – *almost*.

The problem is: while the view is animating its interface-orientation rotation animation, the text appears **warped/stretched**. It looks great before and after the orientation, but wonky *during* the animation.

Is there any way to prevent the view from stretching, and basically imitate the way that UILabels behave when the interface is rotated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `UIViewContentModeTopLeft`.  That's how I solved it in an identical situation in my app.  This will prevent scaling.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456973/1445366).

Comment: Interesting! (To get this approach to work, I had to call `setNeedsDisplay` inside `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`.) It gets pretty close: the text itself no longer stretches, and animates similarly to UILabel. But now the *entire view* animates this way too. It's not super noticeable, but the *view's* frame no longer smoothly animates.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the downsides of using `drawRect` to solve this problem - you can't give each individual item a separate `contentMode`.